# Grep for multiple search with multiple patterns and mutiple options

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

Below is the content:

```
client_name:
client_since:
client_address:
client_city:
client_country_code:
contact_number:
       <some number 1>
       <some number 2>
client_account_number:
client_bank_name:
```

I need to print lines with "**client_name:**", "**client_city:**", "**client_country_code**:" patterns/strings. I also need to print line with "**contact_number:**" & 2 lines after it so that those 2 dynamic lines are printed as well.

How can I achieve that through one-liner command?

Comment: what all you have tried so far?

Comment: @piyushjaiswal grep with -e & -A, grep with -f & -A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -E "client_name:|client_city:|client_country_code:|contact_number:|landline:|mobile:" data
client_name:
client_city:
client_country_code:
contact_number:
       landline:
       mobile:
```

If the two lines below contact number are dynamic then you may use below grep combo:

```
     grep -E "client_name:|client_city:|client_country_code:" data  && grep -A2 "contact_number:" data
client_name:
client_city:
client_country_code:
contact_number:
       landline:
       mobile:
```

**OR**

```
grep -E "client_name:|client_city:|client_country_code:|`grep -A2 contact_number: data`" data
```

Here one dirty way to achieve what you have asked for in comments:

```
grep -Ee "client_name:|client_city:|client_country_code:|`awk '/contact_number/{print; nr[NR+2]; next}; NR in nr' data`" data
client_name:
client_city:
client_country_code:
contact_number:
       mobile:
```

Comment: Hi, I have modified the question. The lines below contact_number are dynamic. I just need to print 2 lines after contact_number. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Great! It works well. How can I skip first line of contact number and only print the second one?

Comment: Also, I wish to store above content in a variable. How can I search from a variable then? @RandomUser

Comment: updated. Please Ask separate question for different questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat data 
client_name:
client_since:
client_address:
client_city:
client_country_code:
contact_number:
       landline:
       mobile:
client_account_number:
client_bank_name:
$ egrep '^(contact_number|\s*landline|\s*mobile|client_(name|city|country_code))' data 
client_name:
client_city:
client_country_code:
contact_number:
       landline:
       mobile:
$
```

Comment: Hi, I have modified the question. The lines below contact_number are dynamic. I just need to print 2 lines after contact_number. Please let me know. Thanks